# Existence and uniqueness of solutions to $x' = t^{1/3} \sqrt{|x| (t^2 + x^2)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find for which initial conditions $(t_0, x_0)$ does the problem given by $$x' = f(t,x) = t^{1/3} \sqrt{|x| (t^2 + x^2)}$$ $$x(t_0) = x_0$$ have solution and this solution is unique.

Since $f(t,x)$ is continuous, according to the Peano theorem the problem has a solution for every election of $(t_0, x_0)$. Also, since $f$ is continuously differentiable if $t_0, x_0 \neq 0$ the solution for these points is unique.

Let's consider now the cases in which $x_0 = 0$ or $t_0 = 0$.

If $x_0 = 0$ then $f(t, x_0) = 0$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $x_0$ is an stable point and $x = x_0$ is the unique solution to the problem. I am not quite sure about this reasoning, is this correct?

I still need to prove (or disprove) uniqueness of the solution in the points of the form $(t_0, x_0) = (0,x_0)$ with $x_0 \neq 0$. I could prove uniqueness if I could check that there exist $L$ such that $|f(t,x) - f(t,y)| \leq L |x-y|$ for pairs $(t,x), (t,y)$ in a neighborhood of $(t_0, x_0)$. But I have not had any luck bounding that difference.

Would it be sufficient to prove that:
$$ \lim_{y \to x} \frac{|f(t,x) - f(t,y)|}{|x-y|}$$
is a constant for $x$ sufficiently close to $x_0$?

Thanks in advance.